# Concatenate two text files using command line (windows) and put the result in the first file

Tags: cmd, concatenation

I have two text files I retrieve from some app that change their name on every load. I am writing a batch script where I want to Concatenate the two text files using command line (windows) and put the result in the first file.

example: `F1_21032022.txt F2_21032022.txt`  ( the changing part is the numbers), I want to merge the result in `F1_21032022.txt`.

`copy /b F1*.txt + F2*.txt F1*.txt` => didn't work

`more F1*.txt F2*.txt >> F1*.txt` => didn't work as well

Please HELP !

Answer (score 0):

This can be used at a `cmd` prompt or in a `batch-file` on `windows`. Note that the file number is selected from the filename by a regex capturing (\d*). This match is used to create the F2_ filename. The `ECHO` commands are just to create test files.

```
ECHO asdf`r`nqewr >"F1_000.txt"
ECHO 1234`r`n5678 >"F2_000.txt"

powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    Get-ChildItem -File -Filter 'F1_*.txt' ^| ^
        ForEach-Object { ^
            if ($_.Name -match 'F1_(\d*)\.txt') { ^
                $OtherFileName = """.\F2_$($Matches[1]).txt"""; ^
                if (Test-Path -Path $OtherFileName) { ^
                    Get-Content -Path $OtherFileName ^| Out-File -FilePath $_.FullName -Append -Encoding ascii ^
                } ^
            } ^
        }
```

This would be more easily written and understood by writing the script in PowerShell. It would avoid the contortions needed to write .bat file scripts. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available.

Comment: Can you please customize it to work for my case, I tried but it didn't work :
Example:
Input files: ADAT_DZ01_20220320_104155.txt   and   AEDAT_DZ01_20220320_104155.txt       Output files:  ADAT_DZ01_20220320_104155.txt (Result of merging the 2 input files)        PS/ the files name changes with every extraction from the app :                  ADAT_DZ01_[the changing part].txt / AEDAT_DZ01_[the changing part].txt                         Thanks !

Comment: The only part common to both files you specify is `_DZ01_`. Do you want to concatenate all `*_DZ01_*.txt` file into `ADAT_DZ01_20220320_104155.txt`?

Comment: No, everytime I extract these files, i obtain: ADAT_DZ01_[Changing Part].txt and AEDAT_DZ01_[Changing Part].txt, I want to concatenate these exact two files into ADAT_DZ01_[Changing Part].txt